# Create choropleth function for Plotly not working

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, geo, choropleth

Hi I am following the plotly tutorial to plot all the US counties. However, I keep getting an error saying: The create_choropleth figure factory requires the plotly-geo package. I have already installed plotly-geo using pip but it is still giving me this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have attached my code below. Thank you

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/laucnty16.csv')
df_sample['State FIPS Code'] = df_sample['State FIPS Code'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2))
df_sample['County FIPS Code'] = df_sample['County FIPS Code'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(3))
df_sample['FIPS'] = df_sample['State FIPS Code'] + df_sample['County FIPS Code']

colorscale = ["#f7fbff","#ebf3fb","#deebf7","#d2e3f3","#c6dbef","#b3d2e9","#9ecae1",
              "#85bcdb","#6baed6","#57a0ce","#4292c6","#3082be","#2171b5","#1361a9",
              "#08519c","#0b4083","#08306b"]
endpts = list(np.linspace(1, 12, len(colorscale) - 1))
fips = df_sample['FIPS'].tolist()
values = df_sample['Unemployment Rate (%)'].tolist()

fig = create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)

py.plot(fig, filename='choropleth_full_usa')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it by moving file over to google drive and running on Google Collaboratory.